# How to validate protobuf messages in a Spring Rest controller in method parameter

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Let's say "TestTask " is protobuf generated java class. I want to send to a REST endpoint as a POST request.

My question is how can I validate the "TestTask" and it's fields ?

1. Will it make sense to add @Validated along with @RequestBody ?

[My view: It does not make any sense to add @Validated since internally protobuf java class does generate any annotations for null-checks or empty-checks. ]

2. If I add @NotNull, will it work ?

[My view: It should work at least for null-check of the object. ]

3. Will it make sense to add both the above annotations along with @RequestBody ?

for ex,  TestTaskComplete processTestTask(@Validated  @RequestBody @NotNull TestTask testTask)

[My View: @Validated  -> does not make sense to add this. rest looks good]

```
@RestController
public class TestTaskEndpoint {

    @PostMapping(value = "/testTask", consumes = "application/x-protobuf", produces = "application/x-protobuf")
    TestTaskComplete processTestTask(@RequestBody TestTask testTask) {
        // TestTask is a generated protobuf class
        return generateResult(testTask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1). adding @Validated or @Valid don't work as the fields in GPB are not annotated.
2). @notNull shouldn't compile as it is not the right place for it.

one way I think it works is to use @initBinder to bind your gpb to POJO and add the validation annotation in your POJO.

let say you create your POJO named TestTaskModel so you can @Valid @RequestBody TestTaskModel model)

in this case, I don't think you need the consumes and produces

Comment: just to give out a bit more information. in the @initBInder method, it converts your GPB stream to POJO.